# Windows - One bluetooth gamepad appears as two gamepads suddenly

Tags: windows, windows-10, bluetooth, game-controller, bluetooth-3.0

My bluetooth gamepad (pg-9023) **appears as two gamepads** (Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Devices and Printers). Additionally in the "Game Controllers" option (image) when I open "Properties" **I can not test/calibrate the gamepad**! =|

[image]

[image]

[image]

This started to happen after the last update of Windows 10. I have already tried to remove and reinstall several times. **What should I do?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the path ...

"Control Panel" -> "Hardware and Sound" -> "Devices and Printers" -> "ipega Extending Game controller"/"OTHER" -> "Properties" -> "Hardware" -> "HID-compliant consumer control device"/"OTHER" -> "Properties" -> "Change settings" -> "Driver" -> "Disable Device" -> "Yes"

Done!

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:** In case of another device with similar problem where is "ipega Extending Game controller" and "HID-compliant consumer control device" replace with equivalent names/values.

Comment: Hey @Erez Zrihen, maybe that's the answer you're looking for! =D